# apidoc not excluding exclude_patterns

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sphinx-apidoc, exclusionpath

I have the following directory structure:

```
+project_name
|
+---project_name
|   |---subpackage
|       |---__init__.py
|       |---api.py
|       |---mock_run.py
|
+---docs
    |---conf.py
```

I don't want mock_run in my docs so in the `conf.py` I have:
`exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store','mock', '**/mock_*', '*/mock_*','mock_run.py']`

I run `sphinx-apidoc -o docs/ project_name -f -M` (I also clean everything like in the `make docs` makefile).

The file still appears in the docs. What am I doing wrong?

As you can see I've tried many different versions for the for the regex to catch so I believe this is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

seems like the exclude_patterns in the conf.py are not for api-doc but for (maybe) the make html.
The solution is to to run the exclude patters for the apidoc in the command line

```
sphinx-apidoc -o docs/ project_name "**/mock_*" -f -M
```

Comment: this one actually worked for me